# CSharp compiler can't open files in parent directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, csc

I'm trying to compile a cs file that is in a sibling directory of my project but csc fails to open it. Here's a sample of the command line that triggers the issue:

```
csc ../test/file.cs
```

Csc prints this message:

```
error CS1504: Source file '<path to current dir>\file.cs' could not be openned
```

The really really strange thing is that it strips the "../test" part.

Anyone has an idea on how to make this work? thanks

Comment: Where in the folder hierarchy are you executing this command?

Comment: I have to directories, let's say "src" and "test"... I'm executing csc when I'm in "src" and I have to compile a cs file in "test".

Comment: "test" and "src" are in the same directory

Comment: I take it you tried `..\test\file.cs` as well?

Comment: Have you tried `csc ..\test\file.cs`?  Windows users \ so that might be the problem

Comment: Ah... great minds think alike.

Comment: yes, I tried this way too... it works only if I use full paths, but I still can't see why it won't work with relative paths

Comment: oh, way a sec... I think this can work but I have to test with msbuild

Comment: Yep, looks like it was a silly mistake, that solves this issue :)
Can you guys post an answer here so I can vote it up?

Comment: @alessandroasm Ehm, which answer? What was it with msbuild?

Comment: Fixing the slash solved the issue... I'm writing a msbuild "script"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is the command line, you should use backslashes to delimit the directories.

```
csc ..\test\file.cs
```

(In a C# program, it wouldn't matter if you'd use backslashes or forward slashes.)